# Pyephem - Time difference between datetime.datetime and ephem.Date

Tags: python, datetime, pyephem

Trying to convert between standard python **datetime** routine datetime.datetime and Pyphem routine **ephem.Date** sometimes there are (except the expected truncation) peculiar differences in the range of one second.

Try the example code:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

import ephem
import datetime

now_datetime = datetime.datetime.now()
now_ephem = ephem.Date(now_datetime)
print "Datetime: ", now_datetime
print "Ephem   : ", now_ephem
```

Repeated calls give an output similar to:

```
thl@thl-lap-001:$ ./timedifference.py
Datetime:  2013-12-20 08:28:11.536814
Ephem   :  2013/12/20 08:28:11
thl@thl-lap-001:$ ./timedifference.py
Datetime:  2013-12-20 08:28:16.088484
Ephem   :  2013/12/20 08:28:15
```

The last two lines show 16.somethig seconds in Datetim that converts to 15 Seconds to ephem.Date.

Is there an explanation?

Answer (score 3):

From [the PyEphem home page](http://rhodesmill.org/pyephem/date.html):

> PyEphem uses a simple floating point number to represent the date and time inside of its astronomy routines.

Floating-point precision always brings some level of approximation. I think that is what you are seeing in your example.

**EDIT**

Upon more digging, the reason it doesn't catch tenths of seconds in this case is that ephem [ignores the microseconds](https://github.com/brandon-rhodes/pyephem/issues/29) when creating a ephem.Date from a datetime. Looks like there is a fix for this coming in version 3.7.5.2

To answer the question

> Isn't python double precision float precise enough to catch at least tenths of seconds in that case?

Most definitely!

```
import ephem
'%f' % ephem.Date('2013/12/20 12:34:56')
=> '41627.024259'
'%f' % ephem.Date('2013/12/20 12:34:56.1')
=> '41627.024260'
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Isn't python double precision float precise enough to catch at least tenths of seconds in that case?